# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning, Version=3.1.0.0 not working in .net core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnet-api-versioning

I am trying to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning, Version=3.1.0.0 in my core api project.

Downloaded the nuget package and below are my code

**statup.cs file**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        //services.AddApiVersioning();
        services.AddApiVersioning
            (o =>
                {
                    //o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true ;
                    //o.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(new DateTime(2016, 7, 1));
                    o.ReportApiVersions = true;
                    o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                    o.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
                    o.ApiVersionReader = new HeaderApiVersionReader("api-version");
                    o.ApiVersionSelector = new CurrentImplementationApiVersionSelector(o);
                }
            );
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseApiVersioning();
        app.UseMvc();

    }
}
```

**and values controller like below**

```
[ApiVersion( "2.0" )]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
 }
```

Now when I am trying a get request from Postman I am getting the values.
As per my understanding it should not provide response as I am not proving any header value for this.

Kindly suggest were I am doing wrong.

### update 1

When I remove this line

```
 o.ApiVersionSelector = new CurrentImplementationApiVersionSelector(o);
```

it is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

[`API Version Selector`](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/API-Version-Selector)

> The **CurrentImplementationApiVersionSelector** selects the maximum API
>   version available which does not have a version status. If no match is
>   found, it falls back to the configured **DefaultApiVersion**. [...]

If you don't provide any api version calling that specific endpoint, it will find the maximum version (In your case 2.0) and use it as a default. That is why the method is being called.

> [...] For example, if the versions "1.0", "2.0", and "3.0-Alpha" are
>   available, then "2.0" will be selected because it's the highest,
>   implemented or released API version.

Comment: This is 99% correct. The reason it's working without you specifying any header at all is because `options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true` is set. The selector resolves the maximum version as described. I'm not sure we have the full picture, but assuming we do, then you should receive a 400 as there is no implementation of `1.0`.